# How to get dropdown menu to push other dropdowns down

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I am trying to fix my mobile view website by having it push the content down when the user clicks on a drop down button, currently what it does is this:

[image]

My current html is below, I just need it to simply push the rest of the content straight down when the user clicks on the dropdown and when they click on something else it pushes it back up:

```
return (
    <nav className={barClasses}>
      <div className="row justify-content-center">
        <div className="imgHolder mr-auto">
          <img src="http://localhost:8080/img/logo.png" className="img" />
        </div>
        <div className="ml-auto">
          <HamburgerButton click={props.closeClickHandler} />
        </div>   
      </div>
      <form className="form-inline mt-5 mb-5 ">
          <input
            type="text"
            className="form-control ml-auto mr-auto"
            placeholder="Search.."
            size="45"
          ></input>
        </form>
      <ul>
        <li className=" mb-5">
          <Link to="/" className="dropDownButton">Home</Link>
        </li>
        <li className="dropDownButton mb-5">
          Masculine
          <ul className="dropDown-menu reg-menu ">
            <li>Test 1</li>
            <li>Test 2</li>
            <li>Test 3</li>
            <li>Test 4</li>
            <li>Test 5</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li className="dropDownButton mb-5 ">
          Feminine
          <ul className="dropDown-menu reg-menu ">
            <li>Test 1</li>
            <li>Test 2</li>
            <li>Test 3</li>
            <li>Test 4</li>
            <li>Test 5</li>

          </ul>
        </li>
        <li className="dropDownButton mb-5">
          Collections
          <ul className="dropDown-menu reg-menu">
            <li>Test 1</li>
            <li>Test 2</li>
            <li>Test 3</li>
            <li>Test 4</li>
            <li>Test 5</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li className="dropDownButton mb-5">
          <a href="#">Contact Us</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  );
};
```

and my css is

```
.dropDownButton {
  float: left;
  max-width: 100%px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 65px;
  line-height: 65px;
  position: relative;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 3rem;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  white-space: nowrap;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.dropDownButton:hover{
  background: #d5d5d5;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.dropDown-menu{
  position: relative;
  top: 0%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
}
.dropDown-menu li {
  background: #666;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  display: none;
}
.dropDown-menu li:hover{
  background: #606060;
}
.dropDownButton-menu li:last-child{
  border-radius: 0px 0px 5px 5px;
}
.dropDownButton:hover .dropDown-menu li {
  display: block;
}
.dropDownButton:hover .dropDown-menu.reg-menu li{
  perspective: 1000px;
  opacity: 0;

  animation-name: reg-menu;
  animation-duration: 500ms;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
@keyframes reg-menu {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateX(0%) translateY(0%);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateX(0%) translateY(100%);
  }
}
```

any help would be appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Your question is missing some things to be considered good: Runnable code, code reduced to the core of the question and code, that has some quality (the code is - besiedes the error you mentioned - not clean at all).

Answer (score 0):

Remove `height: 65px;` from `.dropDownButton` and fix the other styling issues.

```js
let barClasses = 'something';
let closeClickHandler = function() {};

ReactDOM.render(
    <nav className={barClasses}>
      <div className="row justify-content-center">
        <div className="imgHolder mr-auto">
          <img src="http://localhost:8080/img/logo.png" className="img" />
        </div>
        <div className="ml-auto">
          <a click={closeClickHandler} />
        </div>   
      </div>
      <form className="form-inline mt-5 mb-5 ">
          <input
            type="text"
            className="form-control ml-auto mr-auto"
            placeholder="Search.."
            size="45"
          ></input>
        </form>
      <ul>
        <li className=" mb-5">
          Home
        </li>
        <li className="dropDownButton mb-5">
          Masculine
          <ul className="dropDown-menu reg-menu ">
            <li>Test 1</li>
            <li>Test 2</li>
            <li>Test 3</li>
            <li>Test 4</li>
            <li>Test 5</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li className="dropDownButton mb-5 ">
          Feminine
          <ul className="dropDown-menu reg-menu ">
            <li>Test 1</li>
            <li>Test 2</li>
            <li>Test 3</li>
            <li>Test 4</li>
            <li>Test 5</li>

          </ul>
        </li>
        <li className="dropDownButton mb-5">
          Collections
          <ul className="dropDown-menu reg-menu">
            <li>Test 1</li>
            <li>Test 2</li>
            <li>Test 3</li>
            <li>Test 4</li>
            <li>Test 5</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li className="dropDownButton mb-5">
          <a href="#">Contact Us</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```css
.dropDownButton {
  float: left;
  max-width: 100%px;
  width: 100%;
  /* height: 65px; */
  line-height: 65px;
  position: relative;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 3rem;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  white-space: nowrap;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.dropDownButton:hover{
  background: #d5d5d5;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.dropDown-menu{
  position: relative;
  top: 0%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
}
.dropDown-menu li {
  background: #666;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  display: none;
}
.dropDown-menu li:hover{
  background: #606060;
}
.dropDownButton-menu li:last-child{
  border-radius: 0px 0px 5px 5px;
}
.dropDownButton:hover .dropDown-menu li {
  display: block;
}
.dropDownButton:hover .dropDown-menu.reg-menu li{
  perspective: 1000px;
  opacity: 0;

  animation-name: reg-menu;
  animation-duration: 500ms;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
@keyframes reg-menu {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateX(0%) translateY(0%);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateX(0%) translateY(100%);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="react">
```